# How can I prevent unwanted GET requests with URLs added to parameters

Tags: nginx, fail2ban

I have a small ecommerce site, (LEMP stack) and I had used a route like

`my.domain.com/makecart?return_url=....`

as a means of returning to a point in the previous page to assist selection for the cart.

Over a period of months I started getting thousands of `GET` requests with unwanted domain links appended to the `?return_url` parameter.

I have now reprogrammed this return route without the use of any parameters, but my site is still getting the unwanted hits.

e.g.

```
 `76.175.182.173 - - [14/Nov/2018:19:36:08 +0000] "GET /makecart?return_url=http://www.nailartdeltona.com/ HTTP/1.0" 302 364 "http://danielcraig.2bb.ru/click.php.......`
```

I am redirecting such requests to an error page, and have it 'under control' with `fail2ban` but I am gradually filling up memory with banning information.
(Restarting `fail2ban` took over an hour today)

Is there a way to prevent these hits before they are plucked back out of the access log?

Furthermore what are they doing anyway?

Comment: They're probably looking for open proxies. Make sure fail2ban is using an ipset-based banaction.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I have added in `ipset` with `fail2ban` and 24 hours later I have recovered about 25% of the memory. I have over 70,000 banned ips!

Comment: could return a 404 error and maybe these will start to go away eventually.

Comment: I had been returning a 404 for a long time, and the problem seemed to be worsening. `ipset` and `fail2ban` have reduced the requests from around 12 - 15 per minute to about 5 per hour now. I think perhaps it is some kind of SEO code gone mad. Many of the attached urls look to be from legitimate businesses. anyway thanks, @Michael Hampton @danblack